# Python: How would i get a tally of how many times a word shows up in a text file

Tags: python, list

The question is:
Output the number of books existing in each genre type from this text file

the text file is called book_data.txt and contains the following

```html
#Listing showing sample book details 
#AUTHOR, TITLE, FORMAT, PUBLISHER, COST?, STOCK, GENRE
P.G. Wodehouse, Right Ho Jeeves, hb, Penguin, 10.99, 5, fiction
A. Pais, Subtle is the Lord, pb, OUP, 12.99, 2, biography
A. Calaprice, The Quotable Einstein, pb, PUP, 7.99, 6, science
M. Faraday, The Chemical History of a Candle, pb, Cherokee, 5.99, 1, science
C. Smith, Energy and Empire, hb, CUP, 60, 1, science
J. Herschel, Popular Lectures, hb, CUP, 25, 1, science
C.S. Lewis, The Screwtape Letters, pb, Fount, 6.99, 16, religion
J.R.R. Tolkein, The Hobbit, pb, Harper Collins, 7.99, 12, fiction
C.S. Lewis, The Four Loves, pb, Fount, 6.99, 7, religion
E. Heisenberg, Inner Exile, hb, Birkhauser, 24.95, 1, biography
G.G. Stokes, Natural Theology, hb, Black, 30, 1, religion
```

Also there may be adjustments made to the text file, so how would i write code when there is a new genre entered into the text file(the newly entered information would have to be identified and put into the tally)

the desired output is :

science: 4
religion: 3
biography : 2 etc.

Comment: Take a look at `collections.Counter()`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share the code you've written and point out what isn't working with it.

Comment: i havnt yet attempted this question, im not sure what type of code i would use to count the amount of time a word appears without specifying what words to look for

Comment: well...this is not a solving site, but as different direction to using `Counter`, you could use `dict` where key would be genre type and value the amount of books in particular genre

Comment: @JJBANG458 please don't post stuff here you haven't even tried. You should post here if you're stuck on a particular code issue, not because you're not willing to even try writing the code.

Comment: sorry man, im new to coding and completely new to this site, i was more looking to ask what kind of function to use

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.Counter` along with a comprehension expression:

```
from collections import Counter 

def count_genres(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        return Counter(line.rsplit(',', 1)[1].strip() for line in f if line[0] != '#')
```

If you want, you may convert the `Counter` object to a `dict` by doing `dict(Counter(...))`.

Comment: I upvoted, but rather than `lstrip().rstrip()` you can just use `strip()`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following resource here:  [Finding Unique Words in Python](https://pythonexamples.org/python-find-unique-words-in-text-file/#:~:text=Steps%20to%20find%20unique%20words%201%20Read%20text,more%20text%20cleaning%20steps%20here.%20More%20items...%20)

We can try the following:

```
biography = 0
science = 0
#etc...

text_file = open('book_data.txt', 'r')
text = text_file.readlines()

for line in text:
    words = line.split()
    topic = words[-1]
    if topic == "biography":
      biography = biography + 1
    elif topic == "science":
      science = science + 1
    #etc...

text_file.close()
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Supplementary solution to `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import List, Dict

f = """#Listing showing sample book details 
#AUTHOR, TITLE, FORMAT, PUBLISHER, COST?, STOCK, GENRE
P.G. Wodehouse, Right Ho Jeeves, hb, Penguin, 10.99, 5, fiction
A. Pais, Subtle is the Lord, pb, OUP, 12.99, 2, biography
A. Calaprice, The Quotable Einstein, pb, PUP, 7.99, 6, science
M. Faraday, The Chemical History of a Candle, pb, Cherokee, 5.99, 1, science
C. Smith, Energy and Empire, hb, CUP, 60, 1, science
J. Herschel, Popular Lectures, hb, CUP, 25, 1, science
C.S. Lewis, The Screwtape Letters, pb, Fount, 6.99, 16, religion
J.R.R. Tolkein, The Hobbit, pb, Harper Collins, 7.99, 12, fiction
C.S. Lewis, The Four Loves, pb, Fount, 6.99, 7, religion
E. Heisenberg, Inner Exile, hb, Birkhauser, 24.95, 1, biography
G.G. Stokes, Natural Theology, hb, Black, 30, 1, religion
"""

def count_gen(lines: List[str]) -> Dict[str, int]:
    r: Dict[str, int] = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith("#") or not line:
            continue
        *_, genre = line.split(",")
        r[genre.strip()] += 1

    return dict(r)


print(count_gen(f.split("\n")))
```

Here is online sample - [repl.it](https://repl.it/@simca/SO-65099135)